# PHP convert dynamic strings to Datetime

Tags: php, datetime

I have build an importer using php, that imports data from old website to new website ( doesn't matter what they are build in ). The problem is that in the old database, the date field is **VARCHAR** and in the new database it's Date, so I need to convert them all to **Y-m-d**

Here is a list of some of the dates that come in the loop:

```
01/02/1894
abt 1879
Jan 1884
1895-03-30
06/29/1894
1888-03-07
27 Sep 1876
1885-12-06
1928-04-03
April 22,
1930
5 Jul 1891
1906-08-01
December 31, 1917
1903-02-03
31 Jul 1895
1886-09-13
07/04/1911
1891
August 31, 1920
07/25/1884
1904-04-02
April 15, 1896
July 9, 1943
```

I am working on a function that converts most of them by converting string to timestamp and timestamp to date, but some still return an error.

This is an example of date that fails:

> 1894/02/01

This is what I have so far:

```
private function timestamp_to_datetime( $str ) {
        if (($timestamp = strtotime($str)) === false) {
            print  '<br/><p style="color: red;">Fail ' . ' ' . $str . '</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p style="color: green">' . $str . ' -- ' . date('Y-m-d', $timestamp) . '</p>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: `strtotime` may do weird things to dates before midnight Jan 1st 1970 (Unix Epoch) since it creates a Unix timestamp which is defined as the number of seconds since that date  - you'll be better off with [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) ... though that might not help with some of the stranger strings you've got there.

Comment: Yes I understand what you are saying but, see this from another stackoverflow answer:                                                                           $dtime = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m G:i", "13/10 15:00");
$timestamp = $dtime->getTimestamp();                                                                    You actually need to know the format to get the timestamp, and I can't know for each date that comes in the loop

Comment: You could check if the string contains a forward slash if the format is always year month day.

Comment: You don't need `DateTime::createFromFormat()` just `new DateTime($timestring)` - as long as the *time string* matches one of the [supported formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) (same restriction as `strtotime` basically)

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work on some of the weirder date formats perhaps - but if it doesn't, `strtotime` wouldn't work either since `new DateTime` and `strtotime` both have the same [format restrictions](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php):

```
private function timestamp_to_datetime( $str ) {

    // DateTime
    $dt = new DateTime($str);

    // Invalid
    if(!$dt) {
        echo "<br /><p style=\"color: red;\">Fail {$str}</p>";
    }

    // Valid
    else {
        echo "<p style=\"color: green;\">{$str} == {$dt->format('Y-m-d')}</p>";
    }

}
```

This is your method just rewritten to make use of `DateTime` so you don't hit issues with the Unix Epoch.